# Can't type in terminal to Raspberry Pi after SSH

Tags: networking, ssh

For some reason I can't type after I ssh into the Raspberry Pi. These are the steps I have taken.

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

This ssh's my computer to the raspberry pi. After I have done this, I go to an application called realvnc.[image: RealVNC]

From here, I right click the mouse, then select "run". A credential page will appear. Then, finally I can can see realVNC. [image: RealVNC-2]

I am almost to where I want to be. The only problem I am facing now is when I disconnect the ethernet cable the Terminal window stops working. How do you fix this? Thank you all so much in advance.

Comment: Why are you unplugging the network connection *that seems to be in use*? What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: @user535733- thank you for your comment. I am trying to create a headless pi.

Comment: "headless" means no display.  If you disconnect from the network, you can't keep a SSH connection over that network.

Comment: Nmath- I finally got it figured out, not ethernet or cables, monitor or  keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local (without the ethernet cable)
```

Every other step is the same.

This [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOLnIrqmPQc) will give more detail on how I did it. If you like, you can start the video at about 2:38 which where the text file is.

Comment: Don't make us watch a video to understand a solution. That's considerably worse than a typical "link only" answer, which is considered low quality.  Also this answer doesn't make any sense. You still need to be connected to the device. I'm assuming that your solution is to connect via WiFi?